# Pagination - 'List' does not contain a definition for 'PagingInfo'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, pagination, code-first

Hi everyone so I am trying to create an application using asp.net mvc with a code first database that allows the users to be able to create a blog post with as many images as they wish.I am currently trying to make it so that when there is more than 4 posts it paginate. The code works except for this line

@Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("Display", new { page = x }))

where you actually click to view if there is more than 4 posts

Thanks for your help.

Error

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line
>   Error   CS1061  'List' does not contain a definition for 'PagingInfo' and no extension method 'PagingInfo' accepting a first argument of type 'List' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   Crud

Controller

```
public int PageSize = 4;
    public ViewResult Display(int page = 1)
            {
                var posts = db.Posts.Select(d => new PostVM()
                {
                    ID = d.ID,
                    Heading = d.Heading,
                    Body = d.Body,
                    Images = d.Images.Select(i => new ImageVM()
                    {
                        Path = i.Path,
                        DisplayName = i.DisplayName
                    }
                                  ).ToList()
                }).ToList().OrderByDescending(p => p.ID)
                .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
                .Take(PageSize).ToList();
                return View(posts);
            }
```

View

```
@model List<Crud.Models.PostVM>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}


@foreach (var p in Model)
{
    <h3>@p.Heading</h3>
    <p>@p.Body</p>
    foreach (var image in p.Images)
    {
        <img class="img-thumbnail" width="150" height="150" src="~/Images/@image.Path" />
    }
}

<div>
    @Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("Display", new { page = x }))
</div>
```

Model

```
namespace Crud.Models
{
    public partial class PostModel
    {
        public PostModel()
        {
            Images = new List<ImageModel>();
        }
        [Key]
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Heading is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Heading")]
        public string Heading { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Body is Required")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Display(Name = "Body")]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<ImageModel> Images { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> File { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }

    public class ImageModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public virtual PostModel Post { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    }
    public class ImageVM
    {
        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    }
    public partial class PostVM
    {
        public PostVM()
        {
           Images = new List<ImageVM>();
        }

        public int? ID { get; set; }
        public string Heading { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Files { get; set; }
        public List<ImageVM> Images { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<PostModel> Posts { get; set; }
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
    }
    public class PagingInfo
    {
        public int TotalItems { get; set; }
        public int ItemsPerPage { get; set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)TotalItems /
          ItemsPerPage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Html Helper

```
 public static class PagingHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString PageLinks(this HtmlHelper html,PagingInfo pagingInfo,
        Func<int, string> pageUrl)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i <= pagingInfo.TotalPages; i++)
            {
                TagBuilder tag = new TagBuilder("a");
                tag.MergeAttribute("href", pageUrl(i));
                tag.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
                if (i == pagingInfo.CurrentPage)
                {
                    tag.AddCssClass("selected");
                    tag.AddCssClass("btn-primary");
                }
                tag.AddCssClass("btn btn-default");
                result.Append(tag.ToString());
            }
            return MvcHtmlString.Create(result.ToString());
        }
    }
```

repository

```
  public interface IRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<PostModel> Posts { get; }

    }
```

Trying Suggested Solutions

The view

```
    @model Crud.Models.PagedList
```

The Model

```
    public class PagedList
    {
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
        public List<PostVM> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

The Error: wouldn't run

> foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Crud.Models.PagedList' because 'Crud.Models.PagedList' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
>           }

The View

```
    @model Crud.Models.PagedList<Crud.Models.PostVM>
```

The Model

```
 public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
        public List<PostVM> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

The Error :Runtime

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Crud.Models.PostVM]',
>        but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Crud.Models.PagedList`1[Crud.Models.PostVM]'.

Comment: Your `Model` is `List<Crud.Models.PostVM>` (via `@model List<Crud.Models.PostVM>`); a `List<T>` **doesn't have** a `PagingInfo`... what did you expect to happen? where do you expect `PagingInfo` to come from? Either you meant `@model Crud.Models.PostVM`, or you need to talk about the `.PagingInfo` of specific items *in the list*

Comment: Hi Marc I was wondering how would I be able to add the pagingIfo to the list?

Comment: You can't; you can, however, create a custom model that *has* both a `List<PostVM>` and a `PagingInfo` (`class WhateverModel { public List<PostVM> Posts {get;set;} public PagingInfo PagingInfo {get;set;}}`), or you can subclass `List<T>`, for example `class PagedList<T> : List<T> { public PagingInfo PagingInfo {get;set;}}` and use `@model PagedList<PostVM>`

Comment: @MarcGravell Hi Marc thank you for your help but when I tried this   public class PagedList
    {
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
        public List<PostVM> Posts { get; set; }
    }
I got This Error

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Crud.Models.PagedList' because 'Crud.Models.PagedList' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
}

Comment: @MarcGravell and when I tried this  public class PagedList<T> : List<T>
    {
        public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
        public List<PostVM> Posts { get; set; }
    }
 I got this The Error

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[Crud.Models.PostVM]',
       but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Crud.Models.PagedList1[Crud.Models.PostVM]'. I have edited the question to put a suggested solution section at the end so that it will be easier for you to see than here and again thank you for the help :)

Comment: In the first example, you need to for each over the .Posts. In the second example you need to actually use PagedList-T in your controller when calling View, not just List-T

Comment: Why are you trying to reinvent the wheel - use a existing paging plugin such as [Mvc PagedList](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.Mvc)